# Save a format for a node body

Tags: nodes, 8

How do I save the format used for a node body?

I am using the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
$article = Node::create(array('type' => 'article'));
$article->setTitle($node->title);
$article->set('body', "My body...");
$article->setPublished(TRUE);
$article->body->format = 'full_html';
$article->save();
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Fixed:

Right code:

```
$article = Node::create(array('type' => 'article'));
$article->setTitle($node->title);
$article->body->value = $node->body;
$article->body->format = 'full_html';
$article->setPublished(TRUE);
$article->save();
```

Comment: Clarify "does not work", what did you expect and what happens? this looks fine to me, setting the body twice, once with set() and once directly is a bit strange, I'd suggest either pass both value and format to set() or use body->vlue = 'My body'..

Comment: I would also not use the `Node` class directly. The class handling the node entity could be different. There is `entity_create()`.

Comment: @Berdir My Post was edited :( the line what does not work is `$article->body->format = 'full_html';` when I save the node everything were saved except body->format.

Comment: have a look at this link will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172791/how-to-programmatically-create-a-node-in-drupal-8

Comment: Please don't incorporate the answer into the question. Please add a full answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

// $node is supposed to be previously defined node object.

```
$article = Node::create(array(
  'type'     => 'article',
  'langcode' => 'en,
  'title'    => $node->title->value,
  'body'     => ['value' => $node->body->value, 'format' => 'full_html'],
  'status'   => 1,
));
$article->save();
```

This is the code if in case, anyone wants it.

Answer (score 2):

You left out `->value`: it should be `$article->setTitle($node->title->value);` but also `$node->body->value` I think. This likely throws an exception as a result and then something it eats it up so you don't get an error but it's not working indeed.

Comment: `$node` is a object stdClass that I created.

Answer (score 1):

For an existing node, you can set the `body` with `format` simply as follows:

```
$node->body = array('format' => 'full_html', 'value' => $body);
$node->save();
```